# How to store mutually exclusive relationships in a table?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I have a list of departments in a table

```
DeptID | Name 
1        Marketing
2        Sales
3        HR
4        Logistics
5        R&D
```

I need to create another table that shows which departments are mutually exclusive to each other. I imagined something like this:

```
DeptID1 | DeptID2
1         2
1         3
5         2
4         2
```

The table is meant to be indicate that `DeptID1` is incompatible with `DeptID2`. I can foresee that some crazy joins might have to take place to get at data if my DB is designed this way. It also only shows conflicts, but not which ones are valid combinations (another crazy join may be needed to get this information)

Essentially, if a new member of staff joined I'd like the system to show what other departments they could work in that don't conflict with their own. And equally, not show them the ones that conflict.

Is there a better way of storing mutually exclusive relationships?

Comment: It looks like a decent design. I'd recommend adding an auto-incrementing primary surrogate ID column, renaming `DeptID1` to `DeptID` and renaming `DeptID2` to `IncompatibleDeptID`

Comment: "*Is there a better way of storing mutually exclusive relationships?*" This depends a lot on what the source of and reasoning behind the mutual exclusion is.  If there really is no consistent rhyme or reason behind it, then your's is probably the preferred scheme.  However, mutual exclusions usually come about from either category classifications or attribute allocations, in which case there are better ways to do it.

Comment: I'm happy to change the design to accommodate an easier/better way of doing it.

Comment: What crazy joins? Your queries will have things like `...where (x.DeptId,y.proposedDeptId) not in (select * from exclusions)` simply saying that one Id is not excluded by another.